# Error in MySQL and PHP statement

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have the following code, but it seems to break the page at the `$result = $mysqli->query($query);` statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ids = join(',',$newArray);  
$query = "SELECT name, image FROM logos WHERE id IN ($ids)";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $imageLink = $row['logoImageLink'];

 echo "<li><img src=\"$imageLink\"/></li>";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump`ing your `$query`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help us answer the question if you provided the error. Being that I answered your last question:

You most likely need to define `$mysqli`, like so:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

Comment: okay thanks, i was unsure how to do that so I am looking at how to add an error handler.

Comment: Yes this was the problem. Thank you for pointing that out. I don't care if my account takes a beating for this post, i appreciate someone taking the time to come to my level. lol thx again